# replace string from left to right in a line

Tags: text-processing, search, replace

I want to **search and replace** the negative values with the value just before it. The values are separated by comma.

Example:

```
ocv_sigma_cell_rise(table_7) {
    sigma_type : early_and_late;
    values("0.00616, 0.00505, 0.00337, -0.00026");
}
```

In this I need to replace negative value "-0.00026" with the value just before it(here "0.00337").

The negative values need to be searched in a file with "ocv" as a common word.

Comment: Are lists of numbers always surrounded by double quotes like in your example? Are there other constraints that make it easier to parse such lines?

Comment: Is this a contrived sample or a realistic one? Meaning can there be other data within this block or always two lines. What if the first value is negative or whatif all are negative?

Answer (score 0):

For this restricted ocv .lib file you can run this small perl code.

```
perl -lne '
  BEGIN {
    $arc = qr/ocv_sigma_cell_(rise|fall)\([^)]*\)\s*\{/;
    $num = qr/\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+/;
  }
  next unless /$arc/ ... /\}/;
  push @A,$_;next unless /\}/;
  my $var = join "\n", splice @A;
  $var =~
  s{^\s*values\(\K(.*?)(?=\))}
   [
    local $_ = $1;
    1 while s/(?:"|\s)($num),\s+\K-$num(?=,|")/$1/;
     $_;
   ]xmse;
  print $var;
' your_ocv.lib
```

**Output:**

```
ocv_sigma_cell_rise(table_7) {
    sigma_type : early_and_late;
    values("0.00616, 0.00505, 0.00337, 0.00337");
}
```